# Why is the depth texture not being rendered in the second pass?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, shadow

I’m working on my own game engine AND learning OpenGL in the process, and I have got stuck in Shadowmapping for longer than I would like to admit.

I have been following this guide: https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Shadows/Shadow-Mapping But I don’t get to draw any shadow in my plane.

[image: result]

This is how the code looks in my project:

Framebuffer for creating the depth texture:

```
 glCreateFramebuffers(1, &m_framebufferID);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_framebufferID);glGenTextures(1, &depthMapID); 

ui32 depthMapID;    
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMapID);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 1024, 1024, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_framebufferID);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMapID, 0);
ASSERT(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE, "Framebuffer is incomplete!");
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Depth texture shader (ignore the unused vertex layout):

```
#type vertex
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertex_position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 vertex_color;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 vertex_normal;    
layout (location = 3) in vec3 vertex_tangent;
layout (location = 4) in vec2 vertex_texcoord;

uniform mat4 u_lightViewProjectionMatrix;  
uniform mat4 u_worldTransformMatrix; 

void main()
{
    gl_Position = u_lightViewProjectionMatrix * (u_worldTransformMatrix * vec4(vertex_position, 1.0));
}  

#type fragment
#version 330 core

// Ouput data
//layout(location = 0) out float fragmentdepth;

void main(){
    // Not really needed, OpenGL does it anyway
    //fragmentdepth = gl_FragCoord.z;
}
```

This is how I create the shadow map

```
if (s_castingShadowMeshes.Size() == 0)
    return;

float shadowDistance = 100.0f;          
glm::mat4 lightView = glm::lookAt(LightManager::GetDirectionalLight().direction * -shadowDistance, glm::vec3(0.0f), MathUtils::Vector3UnitY);
glm::mat4 lightProjection = glm::ortho(-shadowDistance, shadowDistance, -shadowDistance, shadowDistance, 0.0f, shadowDistance * 2.0f);

s_lightViewProjection = lightProjection * lightView;    

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_framebufferID);
glViewport(0, 0, 1024, 1024); //Shadow height and width is 1024

glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glClearDepth(1.0f);
glClearColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT););

for (ui32 i = 0; i < s_castingShadowMeshes.Size(); ++i)
{
    s_depthMapShader->Bind();
    s_depthMapShader->SetUniform(UNIFORM_LIGHT_SPACE_TRANSFORM, ShaderDataType::Mat4, &(s_lightViewProjection));
    s_depthMapShader->SetUniform(UNIFORM_MODEL_SPACE_TRANSFORM, ShaderDataType::Mat4, &(s_castingShadowMeshes[i]->GetWorldTransform()[0][0]));
    s_rendererPlatformInterface->DrawVertexArray(s_castingShadowMeshes[i]->GetVertexArray());

    s_renderStats.drawCalls++;
    s_depthMapShader->Unbind();
}
s_shadowFramebuffer->Unbind();
```

Up to this point, RenderDoc shows me that a depth texture is actually being generated:

[image: renderdoc depth texture]

Now, this is how rendering the plane looks like:

```
shader->Bind();

ui32 useShadowMapTex = 0;           
if (receiveShadows)
{
    useShadowMapTex = 1;
    ui32 shadowMapSlot = (ui32)Material::TextureSlots::ShadowMap;
    shader->SetUniform(UNIFORM_SHADOWMAP_TEX, ShaderDataType::Int, &shadowMapSlot);
    s_shadowMapTex->Bind(shadowMapSlot);
}

shader->SetUniform(UNIFORM_USE_SHADOWMAP_TEX, ShaderDataType::Int, &useShadowMapTex);
shader->SetUniform(UNIFORM_MODEL_SPACE_TRANSFORM, ShaderDataType::Mat4, &(transform[0][0]));
shader->SetUniform(UNIFORM_VIEW_PROJECTION, ShaderDataType::Mat4, &(s_sceneData.viewProjectionMatrix));
shader->SetUniform(UNIFORM_CAMERA_POS, ShaderDataType::Float3, &(s_sceneData.cameraPosition));

shader->SetUniform(UNIFORM_DIR_LIGHT_DIRECTION, ShaderDataType::Float3, &(LightManager::GetDirectionalLight().direction));
shader->SetUniform(UNIFORM_DIR_LIGHT_AMBIENT,ShaderDataType::Float3, &(LightManager::GetDirectionalLight().ambientColor));
shader->SetUniform(UNIFORM_DIR_LIGHT_DIFUSSE, ShaderDataType::Float3, &(LightManager::GetDirectionalLight().diffuseColor));
shader->SetUniform(UNIFORM_DIR_LIGHT_SPECULAR, ShaderDataType::Float3, &(LightManager::GetDirectionalLight().specularColor));

s_rendererPlatformInterface->DrawVertexArray(vertexArray);

s_renderStats.drawCalls++;
s_renderStats.vertices += vertexArray->GetIndexBuffer()->GetCount();
```

The shader for the plane:

```
#type vertex
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertex_position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 vertex_color;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 vertex_normal;    
layout (location = 3) in vec3 vertex_tangent;
layout (location = 4) in vec2 vertex_texcoord;

out VS_OUT {
    vec3 FragPos;
    vec3 Normal;
    vec2 TexCoords;
    vec4 FragPosLightSpace; 
} vs_out;

uniform mat4 u_viewProjectionMatrix;  
uniform mat4 u_worldTransformMatrix;
uniform mat4 u_lightViewProjectionMatrix;

void main()
{    
    vs_out.FragPos = vec3(u_worldTransformMatrix * vec4(vertex_position, 1.0));
    vs_out.Normal = transpose(inverse(mat3(u_worldTransformMatrix))) * vertex_normal;
    vs_out.TexCoords = vertex_texcoord; 
    vs_out.FragPosLightSpace = u_lightViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(vs_out.FragPos, 1.0);
    gl_Position = u_viewProjectionMatrix* vec4(vs_out.FragPos, 1.0);
}

#type fragment
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in VS_OUT {
    vec3 FragPos;
    vec3 Normal;
    vec2 TexCoords;
    vec4 FragPosLightSpace;
} fs_in;

struct DirectionalLight 
{
    vec3 direction;  

    vec3 ambientColor;
    vec3 diffuseColor;
    vec3 specularColor;
};

uniform DirectionalLight u_directionalLight;
uniform sampler2D u_shadowMapTex;
uniform vec3 u_cameraPos;

float ShadowCalculation(vec4 fragPosLightSpace)
{
    // perform perspective divide
    vec3 projCoords = fragPosLightSpace.xyz / fragPosLightSpace.w;
    // transform to [0,1] range
    projCoords = projCoords * 0.5 + 0.5;
    // get closest depth value from light's perspective (using [0,1] range fragPosLight as coords)
    float closestDepth = texture(u_shadowMapTex, projCoords.xy).r; 
    // get depth of current fragment from light's perspective
    float currentDepth = projCoords.z;
    // check whether current frag pos is in shadow
    float shadow = currentDepth > closestDepth  ? 1.0 : 0.0;

    return shadow;
}

void main()
{           
    vec3 normal = normalize(fs_in.Normal);
    vec3 lightColor = vec3(1.0);
    // ambient
    vec3 ambient = u_directionalLight.ambientColor;
    // diffuse
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(u_directionalLight.direction);
    float diff = max(dot(lightDir, normal), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = diff * lightColor;
    // specular
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(u_cameraPos - fs_in.FragPos);
    float spec = 0.0;
    vec3 halfwayDir = normalize(lightDir + viewDir);  
    spec = pow(max(dot(normal, halfwayDir), 0.0), 64.0);
    vec3 specular = spec * lightColor;    
    // calculate shadow
    float shadow = ShadowCalculation(fs_in.FragPosLightSpace);       
    vec3 lighting = (ambient + (1.0 - shadow) * (diffuse + specular));    

    FragColor = vec4(lighting, 1.0);
}
```

This is what i get:

[image: result]

According to RenderDoc, the shadow map texture is actually being passed in the shader, but it never gets drawn in the red plane:
[image: renderdoc result]

I hope somebody can help me. Many thanks in advance.

p.d: this is my first post ever in StackOverflow, excuse me if i am violating any rule.

Comment: Yes, it was intended. I wanted to show the image at the beginning to give some context about what exactly i am rendering.

Comment: Sorry, this is a lot of code. Debugging OpenGL is IMHO not that simple but doing this by eyes in not self-written code is even harder. I assume, you carefully followed the tutorial. Maybe, the reason is something else you're not aware.

Comment: You said that the shadow map is produced correctly. (When I was struggling with shadow casting I made an additional view for debugging where I always displayed it on screen for better checking.) Thus, I would focus on the last stage where the shadow map has to be applied.

Comment: Looking at your plane shader: I saw all these light and shadow computations. What I missed: Any attribute or uniform to describe the color of the plane. There is `layout (location = 1) in vec3 vertex_color;` but it's never used. OK. Maybe, colors are unused and the plane is textured instead. There are `layout (location = 4) in vec2 vertex_texcoord;` and they are processed in the vertex shader but I couldn't find any usage in the fragment shader.

Comment: So, for testing, color/tex might be ignored to colorize the plane exclusively by lighting (as if the plane color effectively white, i.e. `(1, 1, 1, 1)`). So, this is the last thing which raised my intention: `vec3 lighting = (ambient + (1.0 - shadow) * (diffuse + specular));` (near the bottom of the fragment shader). Have you checked whether `diffuse` or `specular` are not `(0, 0, 0)`? If they were the whole shadow calculation becomes somehow useless (as multiplied with 0), and the `ambient` is the only effective. (I tried to find the `diffuse`/`specular` values in your code but I couldn't.)

Comment: Concerning _Sorry, this is a lot of code._: This is, of course, no critics. That's the problem with OpenGL issues: to reproduce more complex techniques, even a [mcve] needs a wall of code to expose. ;-)

Comment: I found the `diffuse`/`specular` values in the snapshot. They don't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Something else made me suspicious: The rendering of trees (?) has the same shape in the 3d view like in the displayed shadow map (in the last snapshot). Ehem.... This would mean that the light source for shadow casting is identical with the camera position. Hence, the objects just would cover the cast shadows. For the light shading of the objects, you seem to have used another position for light source. This is precisely the position you have to use for the camera when the shadow map itself is rendered. IOW, the contents of shadow map has to be how the scene looks from the light source.

Comment: Wow, so much feedback overnight. Thank you Scheff!

So, the shader for the plane is basically a fast test that i copied from the tutorial page, but it has remanescents of another shader that I was using previously, hence the unused vertex layouts.

The fact that the rendered trees looks almost the same as the shadow map trees is just coincidence. If rotate the directional light, the shadowmap will look different.


As you said, i will focus on the last stage.

Comment: Ah, OK. I just was puzzled by the fact that shading of objects and shadow map weren't matching... Happy debugging.